# Extract the X, Y, Z location of a moving sphere with a fixed camera using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

i'm new to opencv and i would like to apply pose estimation in my project. Basically, what i want to do is extract the X, Y, Z location of a sphere. The camera that detects the sphere is at a fixed location, while the sphere moves in space with respect to a world reference frame.

I understand that you have to do a camera calibration first inorder to extract the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters as discussed here: youtube.com/watch?v=HoBKG82A9xs

I found a pretty good reference that actually explains what i want to do in my project here:
https://www.fdxlabs.com/calculate-x-y-z-real-world-coordinates-from-a-single-camera-using-opencv/
However, the z location is fixed and already known in this project. Moreover, the perspective calibration in the project was done in a fixed plane. Which means that the detection is only accurate at that particular plane.

Now my question is how am i going to apply this in a sphere that moves in space? Or can you suggest a different method to accurately extract the X,Y,Z location? Do i need to use two cameras or a single one will do?

Comment: would be nice to see what you have already done..
this guy has some really nice explanations: 
https://github.com/tizianofiorenzani
you can use either 2 cameras to find the 3D location of your object or you could get the z coordinates using only one camera if you can measure the exact size of the sphere..

Comment: choose some visible and computable points on the sphere (image and object coordinates), relative to the center and use solvePnp function

Comment: So far, i can detect the sphere and extract its center. I also used the opensource camera calibration of opencv to extract the intrinsic parameters of the camera. I am planning to modify the code so i can input more images during the calibration.

Comment: I started computer vision in like two weeks ago, I get the concept but i am still confused on how to implement it with 3D detection. and by the way, i used a sphere as a marker for the end effector of my manipulator.

Answer (score 0):

Of course when it comes to 3D co-ordinates, one can use 2 cameras for depth prediction. However, I suggest you to try one thing. Since you are tracking a sphere, it will be easy for you to track the X and Y coordinates. If the working environment is fixed, you can create a formula for Z coordinate based on the area of the sphere. As you will move away from the camera the area will be reduced and Z coordinate will increase. You can design the formula by try-n-error method, if I move my sphere by 1 feet how much area will be decreased.

If the working environment is changing, you can add a calibration phase at the start of the use. Something like before starting the prediction keep the sphere are level 0, pull it back 1 feet. Push it forward 1 feet.